# Can you create a glusterfs with existing data in a directory?

Tags: network-attached-storage, distributed-filesystems, glusterfs

I'm looking into convert a single server/comp into the start of a glusterfs distributed system. I already have a directory mounted on this server of 24TB RAID. I want to use this initial computer to setup glusterfs with this volume/directory and then add additional bricks/computers soon after. I am unsure if I can use a volume/directory with files in it already.

Comment: Couldn't you test this in a few minutes with a `mkdir` and a few `touch`es?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you could. I just tested with couple of test bricks with data already in it and it worked for me. I am using gluster 3.3 on Centos 6.3